# Why does Django development version not know where my packages are?

Tags: python, django, git, tastypie, sorl-thumbnail

I used to be developing a `Django` app using a stable version (1.6) of Django I got installed on Ubuntu using `sudo apt-get install python-django`, and I also used the Django packages `sorl-thumbnail` and `tastypie`.

I have since wanted to switch to using `Django`'s development version, and so I installed it with the instructions in their documentation:

1. `git clone git://github.com/django/django.git django-trunk`
2. `sudo pip install -e django-trunk/`

On my machine, `Django` is now located in `~/git/django-trunk`.

However, when I go back to my `Django` project directory and run `python manage.py syncdb` I seem to get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/$USER/git/django-trunk/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 427, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/$USER/git/django-trunk/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 391, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/$USER/git/django-trunk/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/$USER/git/django-trunk/django/apps/registry.py", line 84, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/$USER/git/django-trunk/django/apps/base.py", line 86, in create
    "cannot import name '%s' from '%s'" % (cls_name, mod_path))
ImportError: cannot import name 'thumbnail' from 'sorl'
```

**Is this because `Django` no longer knows where my installed `Django` apps are?**

I think they are in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` if that helps...

How do I fix this error and get all my `Django` apps to work with the development version? Did I simply need to `git clone` the `Django` development version into `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, or something else?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you so much in advance!

Comment: You should use [virtual environments](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to operate with several Django versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a virtual environment, and install the dependencies for your project in each virtual environment.

This way, the Python interpreter will have access to the required libraries at all times.  To get started:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-virtualenv
```

This will install any required libraries to make `virtualenv` work; then for each project you start by creating a fresh virtual environment.  All these commands are run as your normal user (without `sudo`):

```
$ virtualenv django_env
$ source django_env/bin/activate
(django_env) $ pip install django tastypie solr-thumbnail
```

Typing `activate` will activate the enviornment, so your shell will point to the correct versions of Python. You'll note the `(django_env)` which indicates the environment is currently active.

From this point on, anything you install will be installed *only* in this virtual environment. Once you are finished working, typing `deactivate` will return you back to the system Python environment:

```
(django_env) $ deactivate
$
```

Comment: So assuming I want to use the `development` version of `Django`, how would I install that in `django_env`?

Comment: Simply activate the environment and then type `pip install -e git+https://github.com/django/django.git#egg=django`

Comment: I seemed to have install `Django` inside my `django_env`, but when I try to run `pip install django tastypie solr-thumbnail` I get:

    Downloading/unpacking tastypie
      Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement tastypie
    Cleaning up...
    No distributions at all found for tastypie
    Storing complete log in /home/$USER/.pip/pip.log

Comment: Ok I saw the mistake. `pip install tastypie` should be `pip install django-tastypie`.